# How do you add a tooltip with TabIndex in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add ToolTips to a software with C#.
My problem is that they ask me as a requirement that they activate when a tabIndex is used.

That's the code that I use to show the tooltips with the cursor;

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.tthelp.SetToolTip(this.cbxUser, "Select a user");
        this.tthelp.SetToolTip(this.txtPas, "Enter your password");
        this.tthelp.SetToolTip(this.btnLogin, "Click on the button or  you can enter");
    }
    //(...)
}
```

Comment: *They activate when a tabIndex is used*. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You could add it in the Entry and Leave event of Control.

For example,

```
var controlTooltipDictionary = new Dictionary<Control, string>
{
    [txtUser] = "Select a user",
    [txtPass] = "Enter your password"
};


foreach (var item in controlTooltipDictionary)
{
    item.Key.Enter += (s, ea) =>
    {
      tthelp.Show(item.Value,item.Key);
    };

    item.Key.Leave += (s, ea) =>
    {
      tthelp.Hide(this);
    };
 }
```